# MCU working with external crystal oscillator removed

Tags: arduino, atmega, atmega1284p

I programmed my atmega1284p using Arduino as ISP.
I set oscillator to 16mhz external crystal.
Everything is working fine but when I upload the blink sketch (where I have set led to blink after 1 sec) it blinks after every 3 seconds. If I switch to internal oscillator is starts to work just fine. I even tried removing the crystal while the program was running and to my surprise the program doesn't stop but continues to blink LED every 3 seconds.
The oscillator is connected to pins 12 and 13 with 2 22pf capacitors.
I am really confused so help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Show us your layout. Crystal oscillators are *very* sensitive to PCB parasitics.

Comment: `I even tried removing the crystal while the program was running` What? o.O How did you do that? How/where is the circuit (MCU, crystal, etc) mounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the bootloader I burned into the microcontroller.
While I was burning it I set the it to use the internal 8mhz so no matter what I did in the IDE it used the 8mhz crystal regardless. So I changed the bootloader setting to use 16mhz external crystal and now it works fine.